# Linking entered dates to column location

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

[image: Screenshot]

I have a spreadsheet with the following format. I was given this spreadsheet to use so I'm not sure what use these formulas for dates have in opposition to normal text.

Along the first 4 rows of each column:

K2: 2017 [=TEXT(K$5,"yyyy")]

K3: April[=TEXT(K$5,"mmmm")]

K4: Wed [=TEXT(K$5,"ddd")]

K5: 05 [=J5+1]

In another sheet, I want to do:

**=Sum(K6:N6)**

**=Sum(K7:N7)**

At the start of every week I have to change the columns to the dates of that week

**=Sum(O6:S6)**

**=Sum(O7:S7)**

Instead of manually entering the range of columns each week for the 40 rows that I have, Is there a way I can type in the date, or the column in a separate cell and use that as the object of the formula so I only have to enter a start column and end column/or date and the list will all update?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the whole picture, but the answer to your question is yes, you can have a special cell (or several cells) where you can keep some parameters.

In order to use the value from such cell in a formula you have to specify it with the "$" characters, this way the address of the cell will not change when you copy/move the formulas around.

So, say, you want the parameter to be in cell A2 - in the formulas you have to use "$A$2".

Another way is to use named ranges. You can assign a name to a cell or range of cells. THe simplest way to do so is to select the cell you want to hold the parameter (let's say it's A2 again) and then click into the box leftmost to the formula bar (where A2 is displayed) and type there a name you'd like to use, for example "STARTDATE" and press Enter. You have just named your cell. Now in a formula you can use STARTDATE instead of cell address, which is even better, because you can use a meaningful name and the formulas will be easier to understand.

Comment: Maybe I can make something work with naming the cells using a date?.

Comment: See the screenshot I added at the start, The first half is Sheet1 and goes over the whole year, the second half you can see in the formula bar I have to update those formulas weekly, manually looking at which column in sheet1 lines up with the dates I need.

I made a small orange box However I don't know anyway to actually link it so that I can just change the date or column in that box and it will change all the formulas.